# Parallax Scrolling jerk caused by float left on one section

Tags: jquery, wordpress, parallax

Working on website for my company and can't seem to find a solution.  It is a parallax scrolling site.  On the gallery section there is a slight jerk and hesitation as that section comes into view.  It is caused by the thumbnails for the image gallery which are li's floated left.  When I get rid of float left it comes into view without the jerking.  Even if I assign inline-block to the li's it still does the jerk.  Not sure why this is.  I am using the cycle plugin for the gallery slide show and simple.carousel.js for the thumbnail carrousel.

Link to the website is http://westendvillage.ram.wpengine.com.

If anyone can help or lead me in the right direction it would be appreciated

Comment: It seems to be an issue with the carousel you are using - set display:none to "div.carousel-frame" through FireBug or Chrome's inspector and the issue goes away. Maybe the script fires some JS when the container comes in view?

Comment: Hey Nikola thanks for the quick response.  I switched out the carousel plugin and tried another.  Same situation.  I guess I will try another.  The stutter with this one is not as much as the other.

Comment: This was fixed a while ago.  I wasn't loading the thumbnails correctly.  I was loading the full image and giving the thumbnail a hard with and heigh instead of calling the thumbnail generated in the backend.  That is what was causing the jerking because the images too large to shrink into thumbnails.  Calling the default thumbnail size of the image I uploaded in the backend got rid of the issue.  Thought I had already put up an answer.